# Laravel controller get foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've got a `CategoryController` which is supposed to get every listing with a certain category. A category can have multiple listings but a listing can't have multiple category's.
My `CategoryController` looks like this:

```
$listings = Listing::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->whereNull('sticky_post')
        ->where('category_id.name', $category)
        ->get();
```

I've tried to get the name of the category with category_id.name but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I get the the category name like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do `category_id.name` try:

```
$category_id = Category::where('name', $category)->first()->id;

$listings = Listing::whereNull('sticky_post')
        ->where('category_id', $category_id)
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Keep in mind that you're also keeping only those `listings` with `sticky_post` null which will affect the result.

I hope it helps!